# Birt Pie Chart Series Label

Tags: eclipse, charts, birt, pie-chart

I have a BIRT chart that works fine, but I need to change the series label from "Series 1" to something useful.  Everything works great except for this, but I can't find the place to change it.

**Edit:**

***I was able to modify the XML directly*** and change the `<SeriesIdentifier>Series 1</SeriesIdentifier>` to `<SeriesIdentifier>Amount</SeriesIdentifier>` to get it to work.  This is OK, but where is the GUI option?

***End Edit***

[image: BIRT Screen Shot]

Answer (score 5):

GUI to achieve this is here:

[image]

Though is some situations this is not sufficient because we need to make it dynamic. In [this radar chart example](http://www.visioneo.org/radar-chart) we want to add the selected year after "Sales": this can be achieved through chart scripting. By selecting the chart and clicking on "script" tab we can put a small code fragment such ("Year" is a report parameter):

```
function beforeDrawLegendItem( lerh, bounds, icsc )
{
    lerh.getLabel().getCaption().setValue("Sales "+getParameterValue("Year"))
}
```